# Startup script can be run multiple times despite pid file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

The reason I'm doing this script is because I want to daemonize supervisord: right now I'm in a cloud host in which I don't have access to the `/etc` or the `sudo` command; this script is my best attempt to do everything from my `/home`. I have this bash script with the `start-stop-daemon` command but it allows me to run it multiple times, and I would like it to just run just once.
So far here is what I got:

```
#! /bin/bash 
SUPERVISORD=/usr/local/bin/supervisord
PIDFILE=/home/user/supervisor/supervisord.pid
OPTS="-c /home/user/supervisor/supervisord.conf -j $PIDFILE"

test -x $SUPERVISORD || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

export PATH="${PATH:+$PATH:}/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

case "$1" in
start)
    log_begin_msg "Starting Supervisor daemon manager..."
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $SUPERVISORD -- $OPTS || log_end_msg 1
    log_end_msg 0
    ;;

stop)
    log_begin_msg "Stopping Supervisor daemon manager..."
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE || log_end_msg 1
    log_end_msg 0
    ;;

restart|reload|force-reload)
    log_begin_msg "Restarting Supervisor daemon manager..."
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry 30 --pidfile $PIDFILE
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $SUPERVISORD -- $OPTS || log_end_msg 1
    log_end_msg 0
    ;;

*)
    log_success_msg "Usage: {start|stop|reload|force-reload|restart}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

I assume when the pid file is created it overwrites the previous one, so doing multiple stops doesn't work either. How can I make this script just run once, and not run multiple processes if I do "script start" 5 times? It should complain saying that the process is already running.

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'll edit my question but the basic idea is "not to start supervisord if it is already running", because if I run script start 5 time it will create 5 processes of supervisord

Comment: If you start a daemon using `sudo service start <daemon>` it will report it is already running if it is, and not restart it.

Comment: Yeah that could work but the problem is I have my server in a cloud host and the `/etc` or `sudo` are locked that's why I did it this way

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do and why you are doing it that way in your question. It will help clarify your question and get you better answers.

Comment: What is the content of /home/user/supervisor/supervisord.pid after you start supervisord? What is a content of the same file after you start a second instance of supervisord?

Comment: Do any of your paths contain spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out what was the problem, my script was not verifying if the process was already running so it just started as many process as you run it, but adding:

```
    if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
      echo "supervisord already running: $PIDFILE" 
      exit 1 
    fi
```

in the `start)` case solved my problem, this verifies if supervisord has generated its respective .pid file and if it exists it does nothing.